# Decoding Help for Firestore Bytes

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, base64, decode

I have a weird compressed Bytes format returned as a String from a firestore database. I am trying to decode into a human-readable format.

```
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03åVÛNÜ0\x10ý\x95UTõi+ù\x12Ûñ¾T\x88mU¤\n(¥O\x15\x0f¾\x8cÁj6F±\x17\x8a\x10ÿ^g\x17\x96mÂ\xad¨Û¢6yHäÑÌ\x9cñÌ9öe\x91\x94®!\x16\x93¯\x97E£fPLn¾Å\x87\x90?ãÂÇÏ§`¼ª\x8b\x89Su\x84«qaB=\x9f5ëNÅ«6\x9cï4\x16¾g\x8ftqº\x88óÍ76\x9b\x9aùLC[d¿\x13o-4Å$µsè\x02ï·!\x81I`¯Cwk_"´\x8b\x84Î\x9bµå\x03Pv¯©/\x96ÎWãUbJ¥\x13\x8a\x00ª\x84ÂL\x02W\x143\x84y)\x11\x11J\x88\x8cÇúxZ«\x8bÝ¥Ãa8õ&\x0eaÆÔúæx\x1dæc\x98úð×P\x95\x88I\x8d\x08Ã\x8es\x85+£\x19w¬,\x05©\x84ä\x95`\x03TSp¾ñÉ\x87fÃÈ\x98UÊ\x11B5Â®r\x14°¶2£Â\x02U\x84;m\x06ÈöOB\nCPóÖÿ&D¯||¯ÎBë;k?ûN\x1c\xad\x8co\x87(t\x085¨¦CÒO}ß\x90]\x1d\x8d\x8bx\x02\x90v\x7f\x1aóÅÒÎ´\x98\x94\x9cQ\x8cHÅÇÝäNUR\x07á<Ï:\x1b\x170S¾Þ;o\xa0\x8dÛ\x0b\nd\x06\x1cÝV²ªhkgôzt\x10tHËI{á\x14"@me)\x16\x96ká(!\x98\x96¶ª(È\x92ðÌ«AS>Í!þ\x81Q¥`(gÖ2J\xadÕ\x02\x1cµØàüTÜ@%È\x00×V\x13Ïó6m\x16\x95¬\x9c\x10H#å2¯\x95à´$X+C\x88.5¯Ð\x90Ú\x07PÃ\x99jÒ(Ï\x12lZxnØú\x7fq¸O¸\x15\x99+\\¢\x12#&zd\x96O\'ó»\x19´Ç¹A£C0\'/\x9fÌ\x8e"*eYr\x8a0\x96\x92h\x81¤P\x9c\x01\x96Yí)\x1d\x9e\x87Ë²69\x94S\x88þ¸Y0³\x7fê\xad\x0c/\x8a²\x1f}L£àF\x0eT\x9a·\x1b\'ív\x88i\x80ázñ\x1f\x14\x0bÍ\x94P9\nV\x8e\x99JXá¬\x90BsR2C\x14\x95\x03D4ë\x87I\x9bîÂÔGe;¡VÇ\x8b\x8e÷FµgÝ$\x92¿¬¦}Å[©)ê©(¦O\x97Q\x13f3hRï:´\x14¯;\x05Ô\x063ï<râ\'ìö½µÝîjê.þ\x0fÅzÐ{Qç³½ç¹\x11\x8bßç\x06°ùîpèï\nÐYÞ¤ÎôX\x8cë\x16ü"\x86£üþ\x00\x08§¶û\'\x0e\x00\x00'
```

So far, I have tried native Python b64 decoding by converting the string to bytes `bytes(response, 'utf-8')` and calling `base64.b64decode` on that resulting in:

```
b'T\xdd\x14N/\x93\x99C\xa3\xe8X&\xeb!\xfdxG\xcf.t\xae\xa9\xa0'
```

When I try dumping in a python interpreter, I get:

```
SyntaxError: bytes can only contain ASCII literal characters
```

Does anyone recognize this type of compression/encoding format? Easy way to decode in Python?